# Unstack one column and create new interact columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to unstack one column (say column 'ads') and create new interaction columns with other columns('clicks' & 'impression'). For example, from:

```
    date    ads   clicks    impression
0    1-1      A       50            60
1    1-2      A       60            90
2    1-3      A        5            10
3    1-1      B      200           300
4    1-2      B      600           800
5    1-4      B     1000          2000
```

to (fillin zero or NA if no data available):

```
    date    clicks.A    impression.A    clicks.B    impression.B
0    1-1          50              60         200             300
1    1-2          60              90         600             800
2    1-3           5              10           0               0
3    1-4           0               0        1000            2000
```

Python code for data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1-1','1-2','1-3','1-1','1-2','1-4'],
                   'ads':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                   'clicks':[50,60,5,200,600,1000],
                   'impression':[60,90,10,300,800,2000]})
# what I want 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1-1','1-2','1-3','1-4'],
                   'clicks.A':[50,60,5,0],
                   'impression.A':[60,90,10,0],
                   'clicks.B':[200,600,0,1000],
                   'impression.B':[300,800,0,2000]})
```

I can complete the job via a for-loop, but the large scale of my data does not allow me to do so. Is there a more efficient way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play a bit with indexes, and then `unstack`:

```py
>>> df = df.set_index(["date", "ads"]).unstack("ads").fillna(0)
>>> df.columns = map(".".join, df.columns)
>>> df
      clicks.A  clicks.B  impression.A  impression.B
date                                                
1-1       50.0     200.0          60.0         300.0
1-2       60.0     600.0          90.0         800.0
1-3        5.0       0.0          10.0           0.0
1-4        0.0    1000.0           0.0        2000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table) with fill_value=0 (benefit of using fill_value is that the type of the column will not change due to `NaN` values), then collapse the MultiIndex with [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html#pandas-index-map):

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(index='date',
                        columns='ads',
                        values=['clicks', 'impression'],
                        fill_value=0)
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map('.'.join)  # Join columns with '.'
new_df = new_df.reset_index()  # Turn `date` back into column
```

`new_df`:

```
  date  clicks.A  clicks.B  impression.A  impression.B
0  1-1        50       200            60           300
1  1-2        60       600            90           800
2  1-3         5         0            10             0
3  1-4         0      1000             0          2000
```